# MacBook Pro hangs up at the grey Apple login screen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup

After it would hang up, the keyboard lights would stay lit indefinitely. I've tried resetting the SMC and NVRAM but they didn't work. I did a verbose startup and this was the screenshot before my computer hung up.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: Can you start your mac in recovery modus?

Comment: Screenshot is rather illegible. Can you edit with a new image and focus in more on the left side of the screen?

Comment: Just tried it in recovery mode. It did the same thing but now, it spoke. It said, "To use English as your language, press the return key." But the screen was still black.  I pressed the return key and nothing happened